# Find full path of a gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

How do I find the full installation path of a gem in rails.

```
bundle show gem_name
```

gives

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/gem_name-version
```

My problem is, what directory is the 'var' folder in? I've tried looking in C:/Ruby but it's a really large folder and I don't want to spend all day manually combing my hard drive.

Comment: root(/) directory ...

Comment: @RajarshiDas how exactly do I use that command? The variations I've tried are giving me syntax errors.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On Windows, you typically find them back in (depending on your ruby version)

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems
```

From within your Rails application, you can also run

```
Gem.loaded_specs['gem_name'].full_gem_path
```

Comment: I don't seem to have a RailsInstaller folder but removing that from the path still takes me to a directory of gems. Unfortunately the one I'm looking for is not there.

Comment: Then I suggest you run the command I added to my answer from within your application. Run "rails c" in a command shell, then execute the command

Comment: That still gives me \var\lib.....I'm running my project through a virtual server which I think might be the issue. I think I'm just gonna install the gem on windows and take it from there. Thanks @Danny.

Comment: Because I've installed the gem on windows I can now find it using the path you first specified. Thanks for your help :)